# Printing two related lists

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I have an issue that I can't wrap my head around.
I have two lists containing related information. The structure of the list is as follows:

```
List_a = [(id_nr, date, event), (...)]
List_b = [(id_nr, Item, price), (...), (...)]
```

There can be many items in List_b related by id nr to items in List_a. So the information can look like this

```
List_a = [(1, '2023-01-01', 'Groceries'), (2, '2023-01-02', 'IKEA')]
List_b = [(1, 'Bread', 20), (1, 'Milk', 10), (2, 'Chair', 125), (2, 'Sofa', 230), (2, 'Bed', 340)]
```

What I want is for these to be printed like this:

```
1, 2023-01-01, Groceries
1, Bread, 20
1, Milk, 10
2, 2023-01-02, IKEA
2, Chair, 125
2, Sofa, 230
2, Bed, 340
```

I've tried nested for loops like for instance:

```
For a in List_a:
    Print((a[0], a[1], a[2]))
   
    For b in List_b
    Print((b[0], b[1], b[2]))
```

I've also tried it with while loops in the code, but it either results in an error or I get the first item of the first List, then all the items of the second list and then finally all the items of the first List.

Does anyone have a good way of solving this?

Comment: Are the lists sorted by their first number in the tuple?

Comment: Yes correct. The lists are sorted by the first number. Thanks alot. This really helped  :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two list are sorted by the first number in the tuples and that there is at least one match between the two lists:

```
List_a = [(1, '2023-01-01', 'Groceries'), (2, '2023-01-02', 'IKEA')]
List_b = [(1, 'Bread', 20), (1, 'Milk', 10), (2, 'Chair', 125), (2, 'Sofa', 230), (2, 'Bed', 340)]

idx = 0
for tup in List_a:
    print(*tup, sep=', ')
    while idx < len(List_b) and List_b[idx][0] == tup[0]:
        print(*List_b[idx], sep=', ')
        idx += 1
```

If List_b is not necessarily sorted or grouped by id, then first collect the matching tuples in a dictionary indexed by the first value of the tuple:

```
dic_b = {}
for t in List_b:
    dic_b.setdefault(t[0], []).append(t)

idx = 0
for tup in List_a:
    print(*tup, sep=', ')
    for t in dic_b.get(tup[0], []):
        print(*t, sep=', ')
```

Output:

```
1, 2023-01-01, Groceries
1, Bread, 20
1, Milk, 10
2, 2023-01-02, IKEA
2, Chair, 125
2, Sofa, 230
2, Bed, 340
```